# How do I convert an image to a binary image in QT?

Tags: qt, binary, grayscale

I have a normal .jpeg-file that I want to convert to a binary file with only pure black and pure white colours. I have already managed to convert an image to grayscale with code in QT.

```
QPixmap original(fileName);
QImage rgb2Gray;
rgb2Gray = original.toImage().convertToFormat(QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
QPixmap grayScale = original.fromImage(rgb2Gray);
```

However, I want to convert this grayscale image to a binary image.

Does anyone have any tips on how to do this?

Comment: Did you try QImage::Format_Mono/QImage::Format_MonoLSB? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#Format-enum

Comment: Yes, I have tried both. However, I want a binary image without dithering. Mono and MonoLSB give me the Floyd-Steinberg dithering. The following website gives an examples of my problem: http://www.wikiwand.com/en/List_of_color_palettes. Hopefully you know a way around this dithering issue?

Comment: You might have to do it manually then. create a new image with the same size as the original and one of those formats, and then iterate over the pixels and do the conversion to black/white yourself.

Comment: How do I iterate over all pixels in QT? I have already thought about iterating over the pixels but I couldn't get it working. Any help?

Comment: With two for loops: `for(int x = 0; x < img.height(); ++x) { for(int y = 0; y < img.width(); ++y) { out.setPixel(x, y, qGray(img.pixel(x, y)) > 128 ? 1 : 0); } }` or similar

Comment: You can also use `scanLine(y)` for improved performance, IF that is an issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, iterating through the pixels like you show me, does not work. The result I get is a total black image. No white present. Any idea why?

Comment: This is how I did it:     QPixmap grayScale = original.fromImage(rgb2Gray);

    QImage gray2Binary = grayScale.toImage();
    QImage binary = gray2Binary;

    for(int i = 0; i < gray2Binary.width(); ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < gray2Binary.height(); ++j)
        {
            binary.setPixel(i, j, qGray(gray2Binary.pixel(i, j)) > 128 ? 1 : 0);
        }
    }

    QPixmap binaryImage = binaryImage.fromImage(binary);

Comment: What is wrong with that code?